# Небольшой вопрос по OPEN MP

Tags: c++, openmp

Задание нужно распараллелить с помощью **OpenMP**.

> Разработайте программу для нахождения произведения всех элементов
>   вектора.

если взять 10000 любых элементов, то при перемножении либо выйдет за пределы long(double), либо вернет 0 при перемножении десятичных дробей. А если брать 10 элементов, то что тут параллелить))))

**что предложите сделать?:)**

Comment: Не факт. Например, 0.1 - 10 - 0.1 - 10 - ... :)

Comment: @Harry оо спасибо))) как вариант